# How to pass multiple check box value using (data-value attribute)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Hello Good Day fellow programmers,

How to pass multiple checkbox value using data-value attribute ,so that I can managed to pass it through my controller using public ActionResult (List items) when a delete button is clicked.

**CSHTML:**

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.ReportTrfPendingList)
                {
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" data-value="@item.trfbch"/></td>
                    <td>@item.trfpon</td>
                    <td>@item.dptnam</td>
                    <td>@item.trfbch</td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary deleteBtn" data-value="@item.trfbch">Delete</button></td>

                    <td>@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(Convert.ToInt32(@item.trfsdt.Value.ToString().Substring(2, 2)))&nbsp; @item.trfsdt.Value.ToString().Substring(4, 2)&nbsp;&#44; @DateTime.Now.Year.ToString().Substring(0, 2)@item.trfsdt.Value.ToString().Substring(0, 2)</td>



                </tr>

                }
            </tbody>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
   $("#SelectDeleteBtn").click(function () {

    ---< Processing events here > ---

});
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
     [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SelectedTransferNoDeletion(List<string> items, string deletionNotes) {

        foreach (var transferNo in items)
        {

            var result = deletePendingSrv.SaveDeletionPending(transferNo, SessionUserInfo.Username, deletionNotes);

        }
        return Json(BaseVariable.DEFAULT_SUCCESS);


    }
```

**VIEW :**

Selecting Multiple Check Box value using data-value attribute.

[image: Sample Image of my Project]

Comment: Are you wanting to post back all the values generated by `data-value="@item.trfbch"` in one action?

Comment: Yes. @StephenMuecke . "item.trfbch"  already displayed through my view model.

Comment: And where does the `deletionNotes` come from? (you just need to get all the checkboxes that are checked (`$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')`) and then you can loop through them to read the value)

Comment: @StephenMuecke deletion Notes came from my modal. when the selected button is clicked. modal will come out. and a textarea will appear from the modal itself. `SelectedDeleteBtn`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through each checked checkbox and generate an array based on the `data-value` attribute

```
var items = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function () {
    return $(this).data('value');
}).get();
```

You have not indicated in the question where the value for `deletionNotes` comes from, but assuming its an input, then

```
var deletionNotes = $(someElement).val();
```

You can then use ajax to post the data to your controller

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '@Url.Action("SelectedTransferNoDeletion")', // assumes its in the same controller
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ items: items, deletionNotes: deletionNotes }),
    dataType: 'json'
    success: function(response) {
        ....
    },
    ....
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript event listener to add value of data-value to an array, then you just need to pass that array as parameters to controller.

The simple solution looks like this

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.ReportTrfPendingList)
            {
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" onClick="checkBoxOnClicked()" data-value="@item.trfbch"/></td>
                <td>@item.trfpon</td>
                <td>@item.dptnam</td>
                <td>@item.trfbch</td>
                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary deleteBtn" data-value="@item.trfbch">Delete</button></td>

                <td>@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(Convert.ToInt32(@item.trfsdt.Value.ToString().Substring(2, 2)))&nbsp; @item.trfsdt.Value.ToString().Substring(4, 2)&nbsp;&#44; @DateTime.Now.Year.ToString().Substring(0, 2)@item.trfsdt.Value.ToString().Substring(0, 2)</td>



            </tr>

            }
        </tbody>


  <script>
    var selectedValues = []
    function checkBoxOnClicked(e){
       var value = e.target.getAttribute("data-value");
       if(selectedValues.includes(value)) // ES6 or selectedValues.indexOf(value) >= 0 // older browser{
          selectedValues.pop(value);
       }
       else {
          selectedValues.push(value);
       }
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: That adds the value when you uncheck a checkbox (and will add the same value multiple times if checked or unchecked multiple times)